# Regularity of boltzmann-grad limit and time restriction in Lanford's theorem

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

I have two questions related to the Lanford's theorem, wich states the convergence almost everywhere (as $N\longrightarrow\infty$, for a short time and under a decay assumption on speed) of the first marginal of the $N$-particles distribution function $f_{t:N}$ (associated to an continuous initial distribution $f_{0}$) to a solution $f_{t}$ of the Boltzmann equation.

First I would like to know why is there a restriction on the time? The formulation of the theorem seems to ensure that the $T$ such that the theorem apply in $[0,T]$ depends only of the initial decay of speed so, as the $f_{t}$ obtained here depend only of $f_{0}$, we would want to set $t_{0}:=T/2$ then apply the theorem again to obtain a solution on $[0,3T/2]$ etc... So I suppose that the decay hypothesis does not remain true for $f_{t}, t\neq 0$? Is that correct? If it isn't the case, what kind of problem cause this limitation?

My second question is do we know if any such solution $f_{t}$ is smooth (almost everywhere in space-time or everywhere for $t> 0$)? I know there are some papers on smoothness of some solutions of Boltzmann but, being completely stranger to the field, I can't tell if the solutions provided by Lanford's theorem fall in one of those methods.